# Free jqGrid 3.8.0 - Reset the page counter for sake of filtering

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I'm having an internal manipulation over the paging mechanism, so I get the ofset using:

```
xhr.getResponseHeader("X-list-paging-offset")
```

And the total using:

```
xhr.getResponseHeader("X-list-size");
```

During the callback "beforeProcessing".

So far, so good.  The issue I have is with the filtering.  When I filter the results while I'm on the 3rd page (example), suppose the filter ends up with only one page of results, I stay on the 3rd page which is empty....

My question is, how do I know to "reset" the page counter when I'm doing filtering? so that the pager will always reset to 1 when filter is initiated?

Thanks,

Tal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's strange, because during filtering the `page` parameter will be explicitly set to `1`. **I suppose that you should search for the origin on the problem in the code of `beforeProcessing` which you don't posted here.** By the way you can use `var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam");` or `var p = this.p;` to get the option of jqGrid inside of `beforeProcessing`. You can test `p.search` or `p.postData` to get jqGrid used in request to the server. You can use the value in your logic of `beforeProcessing` callback. I recommend you to use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or Developer Tools of IE/Chrome/Firefox to verify that `page` number which will be set to the server is 1 during searching or searching reset.

Only if will find that the reason of the problem is do in wrong options of `reloadGrid` then I can suggest you an alternative. The current version of free jqGrid from GitHub (the feature included after publishing 4.8 version) contains `reloadGridSearchOptions`, `reloadGridResetOptions` and `reloadGridOptions` options. It can be that the option can help you. The options `reloadGridSearchOptions`, `reloadGridResetOptions` are supported inside of `searchGrid` and `triggerToolbar`/`clearToolbar` of `filterToolbar`. One can use the grid option `searching` or `$.jgrid.search` to specify it.

The methods `editGridRow`, `delGridRow` and `navGrid` support `reloadGridOptions` options. One can use jqGrid option `formEditing`, `formDeleting` and `navOptions` to specify the option `reloadGridOptions` or  `$.jgrid.edit`, `$.jgrid.del`, `$.jgrid.nav`.

Moreover jqGrid support now `reloadGridOptions` option and so the option 
`$.jgrid.defaults.reloadGridOptions` too.

All the above options allows to specify any `reloadGrid` options used during reloading.

Comment: Thanks,  I actually find out that the root cause was because of not placing it within the beforeRequest.  beforeProcessing is happening after the request was fired to the server.

Comment: @Tal: By the way, starting with 15 reputation point you have right to **vote** answers and questions by clicking on arrow up on the left part. You can vote up to 30 questions and answers **per day** (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/147495)). You should understand that the goal of voting is: **the user defined which information is more helpful and which not**. Searching engine use voting as the main criteria. So by voting you help other users to find the information on stackoverflow. You should just no time vote multiple answers *in short time*, such voting will be removed.